# Initial backbone route on page load is not triggered when using router.route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frontend

**This works.**

```
Admin.Routers.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  // home() gets trigger when I visit http://example.com/admin
  routes: {
    "admin": "home"
  },

  initialize: function() {},

  home: function() {
    log("Home");
  }
});
```

**This does not work.**

```
Admin.Routers.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function() {    
    var that = this;

    // home() DOES NOT get trigger when I visit http://example.com/admin
    this.route(/^\/admin$/, "home", function() {
      that.home();
    });
  },

  home: function() {
    log("Home");
  }
});
```

Is this the correct functionality of router.route?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `{pushState: true}` based on the example urls you have posted.  Can you try the following?

```
this.route("admin", "home", function() {
      that.home();
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. But why would the regex not get triggered on load?

Comment: well my next suggestion was going to be to remove the leading forward slash.  Can you try `/^admin$/` as your regEx expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
Backbone.history.start({ silent: false });
```

Comment: consider explaining your answer instead of just posting code which others may or may not understand the significance of